# XCode 7 Instruments - Why is this leaking?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks

I fell into a strange thing: Why is the following code fragment producting leaks (attrDefault not released)? (assume, 'font' has been defined before and self.text refers to an NSString*):

```
{
    NSStringDrawingContext* context = [[NSStringDrawingContext alloc] init];
    NSDictionary* attrDefault  = @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor],
                                    NSBackgroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor clearColor],
                                    NSFontAttributeName : font,
                                    };
    frame.size.height = 1024;
    CGRect bounding = [self.text boundingRectWithSize:frame.size 
                                              options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading|NSStringDrawingUsesDeviceMetrics
                                           attributes:attrDefault context:context];
    frame.size.height = bounding.size.height;

    [context release];
}
```

Any idea?

Update:

Surprisingly, if the same code is embedded into an @autoreleasepool statement, the leaks are gone.

```
@autoreleasepool {
    NSStringDrawingContext* context = [[NSStringDrawingContext alloc] init];
    NSDictionary* attrDefault  = @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor],
                                    NSBackgroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor clearColor],
                                    NSFontAttributeName : font,
                                    };
    frame.size.height = 1024;
    NSString* text = self.text;
    CGRect bounding = [text boundingRectWithSize:frame.size 
                                         options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading|NSStringDrawingUsesDeviceMetrics
                                      attributes:attrDefault context:context];
    frame.size.height = bounding.size.height;

    [context release]; }
```

I did not get any leaks with XCode 6, by the way.

This is pretty strange, as I use NSDictionary constructors ( @{....} ) at a lot of locations in my code and the DO NOT produce any leaks.

Anybody with similiar experience?

Comment: What are you using to detect the leaks?

Comment: Instruments and XCode's memory inspector.